# PIXEL as another user

Tags: login, pixel

I have upgraded my pi3 to the latest pixel version, when I log in as user pi I get the new pixel desktop, however if I log in as another user I get the old LXDE-PI desktop. I've created a new user and that get the pixel desktop.

question is, how do I get the existing user to access the pixel desktop

Answer (score 2):

I found it eventually ... its to do with the .config folder, just copied that over to the other account and its now (nearly) normal